# Zend Framework: Highlight Current Link in menu

Tags: zend-framework, menu

As stated in question title, is it possible in any way to highlight current link in menu? Menu is pure HTML, created manually.

Sergio E.

Comment: Not with PHP. You may want to look at JavaScript or CSS for that purpose.

Comment: I know how to, but how to get current controller and then make something =  if current controller = home add class current :)

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do this. Using:

> Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();

How to make this variable accessible in every controller? :)

Comment: It is. Recieved from static FrontController... it's available everywhere. Even easier - you can use (in controller) $this->_request->getControllerName()